# What is it the new field 'new_like_count'?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I couldn't help noticing yesterday that on the Graph API, a normal request for a page you're owner of, (like let's say http://graph.facebook.com/AnyPageYouAreAdmin with you being authenticated (you can try the call [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/))) would return a new field. This field is called 'new_like_count' and I kind of imagine what is it for. I can guess it will measure the growth of your fans.

What I would like to know is some extra information about it, like for how many days Facebook counts a 'like' as 'new' and these sort of specs that will make the field useful for developers.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Julio,

The new_like_count is the number of new likes since the page has been viewed - this is only viewable by the page admin.

Comment: What do you mean by _'since the page has been viewed'_. Viewed by who? By the admin? Define 'viewed'. Could you explain it (in case you actually know it) a bit further?

Comment: Viewed by the Admin, the Admin is only person this data is visible to. This count is the same as the one you see when you login as the Page. Does that clear things up?